# Issue with log_2 scaling using ggplot2 and log2_trans()

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I am trying to plot data using ggplot2 in R.
The datapoints occur for each 2^i-th x-value (4, 8, 16, 32,...). For that reason, I want to scale my x-Axis by log_2 so that my datapoints are spread out evenly. Currently most of the datapoints are clustered on the left side, making my plot hard to read (see first image).
I used the following command to get this image:

```
ggplot(summary, aes(x=xData, y=yData, colour=groups)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=yData-se, ymax=yData+se), width=2000, position=pd) +
geom_line(position=pd) +
geom_point(size=3, position=pd)
```

[image: Plot without scaling]

However trying to scale my x-axis with log2_trans yields the second image, which is not what I expected and does not follow my data.
Code used:

```
ggplot(summary, aes(x=settings.numPoints, y=benchmark.costs.average, colour=solver.name)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=benchmark.costs.average-se, ymax=benchmark.costs.average+se), width=2000, position=pd) +
geom_line(position=pd) +
geom_point(size=3, position=pd) +
scale_x_continuous(trans = log2_trans(),
                 breaks = trans_breaks("log2", function(x) 2^x),
                 labels = trans_format("log2", math_format(2^.x)))
```

[image: wrong log2 scaling]

Using `scale_x_continuous(trans = log2_trans())` only doesn't help either.

**EDIT:**

Attached the data for reproducing the results:
https://pastebin.com/N1W0z11x

**EDIT 2:**
I have used the function `pd <- position_dodge(1000)` to avoid overlapping of my error bars, which caused the problem.
Removing the `position=pd` statements solved the issue

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include some data so others can try to reproduce your problem. Use `dput` to make the data easy to import. I suspect your problem is with the width argument.

Comment: I have added the data now via a pastebin link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the function `pd <- position_dodge(1000)` to avoid overlapping of my error bars, which caused the problem.
Adjusting the amount of position dodge and the with of the error bars according to the new scaling solved the problem.

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.2) # move them .2 to the left and right

ggplot(summary, aes(x=settings.numPoints, y=benchmark.costs.average, colour=algorithm)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=benchmark.costs.average-se, ymax=benchmark.costs.average+se), width=0.4, position=pd) +
geom_line(position=pd) +
geom_point(size=3, position=pd) +
scale_x_continuous(
  trans = "log2",
  labels = scales::math_format(2^.x, format = log2)
)
```

[image]

Adding `scale_y_continuous(trans="log2")` yields the results I was looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you could format your x-axis:

```
# Generate dummy data
x <- 2^seq(1, 10)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(x, x, x),
  y = c(0.5*x, x, 1.5*x),
  z = rep(letters[seq_len(3)], each = length(x))
)
```

The plot of this would look like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Adjusting the x-axis would work like so:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans = "log2",
    labels = scales::math_format(2^.x, format = log2)
  )
```

[image]

The labels argument is just so you have labels in the format `2^x`, you could change that to whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i get similar results as with my attempts to scale the x-Axis. Maybe the data I use causes the problems. I exported the sample data using ```dput``` and attached them to the original post via a pastebin link.